# How to simplify transition from Apps Script libraries to AddOn?

Tags: google-apps-script

When developing Google Apps Scripts, I make use of libraries since there's lots of shared code. If I have a library `A`:

`function foo() { ... }`

Then if I use that library in another script, `B`, the `foo` function is exposed via a library resource and gets called like:

`function bar() {
  A.foo();
  ...
}`

However, the Google AddOn documentation says to never use libraries. So I prep the AddOn by combining all the library files, which puts everything in the same context, and now the same call from `bar` should be `foo()` and not `A.foo()`.

I've been trying to think of some trick or way of doing all this that will allow me to combine the files without going through and rewriting all the library function calls (e.g., find '`A.`' replace '') or transferring all the functions to an object (e.g., `A = { foo: function() {...} }`). I'd like to be able to just copy and paste all the library bits, but I can't figure (or find) a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this little example help? There might be a better/easier way to do it, but it works with minimal editing of the original library. The other common method of exposing a library's functions don't seem to work with apps script.

### Option 1:

```js
var a = new A();

function main() {
  Logger.log(a.foo());
}

function A() {
  var self = this;

  self.foo = function() {
    return "Hello, world!";
  }

  function bar() {
    return "I'm private!";
  }
}
```

---

### Option 2:

A little more complicated using prototype...

```js
function main() {
  var a = new A();
  Logger.log(a.foo());
}

var A = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.bar = function() {
    return "World!";
  }
}

A.prototype.foo = function() { //Prototype public stuff
  return "Hello, " + this.bar();
}
```

---

Either way they will have to modified a bit. Does anybody else know a better way?

Comment: Yeah, it's about in line with the 'search/replace' method I'm using now in terms of the modifications. It's a little odd because everything else about Apps Scripts seems pretty well thought out but the whole "no libraries" thing when converting to AddOns is a bit clunky.

Comment: @zanerock I mean, ideally, the library should be developed like this in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean develop without libraries? The problem is that I'm working on multiple add-ons and private scripts all at once, and so it's desirable and best practice to abstract much of that work into libraries; otherwise, I'd have dozens of duplicate copies of the same code to maintain. The best workflow I have at the moment is to develop with libraries, and then go through a manual copy-paste-modify routine to prepare the library free AddOns.

Comment: @zanerock Oh, no! I did not mean that at all!! Haha, sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant that ideally the library should be made in the format I posted in the first place (prototype method is common in open-source, popular libraries - see tag wiki). The current system just isn't very convenient.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Yeah, it seems like an odd oversight. I think my next project will be something to assemble the publishable AddOn from constituent libraries through a simple/automated inlining process; unless Google fixes this first.